# Magento 2. APIs. What is Content Tagging?

Tags: magento2, api

I'm looking here 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Under **What can I do with the Magento web APIs?**, you can find **Integrate with a CMS (Content Management System). At present, `content tagging` is not supported.**

What do they mean by **content-tagging**. An example will help too.
Cheers.